# Python Requests - Grabbing Website Cookies

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have the below simple script trying to grab and print session cookies from the states URL:

```
import sys
import os
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


url = ''.join(('http://www.canada.com/entertainment/television/tv-listings/index.html#f=grid'))
                                     
session = requests.Session()
session.mount(url, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
                                 
headers ={
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
                     
req = session.get(url, headers=headers)

print(str(req.cookies.get_dict()))
```

The code runs with no errors, however I am just getting an empty dict returned. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you see the website response headers, there is no cookie set in the response headers. Hence, you are getting empty dictionary.

[image]

You can see that in the response too

```
In [34]: import sys
    ...: import os
    ...: import requests
    ...: from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: url = ''.join(('http://www.canada.com/entertainment/television/tv-listings/index.html#f=grid'))
    ...:
    ...: session = requests.Session()
    ...: session.mount(url, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
    ...:
    ...: headers ={
    ...: 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    ...: 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3
    ...: 325.181 Safari/537.36'
    ...: }
    ...:
    ...: req = session.get(url, headers=headers)

In [36]: req.headers
Out[36]: {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '17874', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Expires': '-1', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'X-AspNet-Version': '2.0.50727', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'P3P': "CP='NOI DSP COR NID CUR ADMo DEVi TAIi PSAi OTPo OUR SAMi UNRi OTRi BUS UNI COM NAV INT STA'", 'Date': 'Tue, 21 Jul 2020 23:50:03 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 c1bfbbe7d455db5795b7f7a2882ec537.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'BLR50-C2', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'O_2Z-96k4NNyJkmkewKmj9YlJ7iphXJOEtvzyH8CKHPD1V-JBMp3fg=='}
```